# Simple SharpMap example to create shape file

Tags: c#, .net, sharpmap

I'm looking to create a simple shape file using sharpmap (or some other library if it's easy/free). I want a shape file with just some lat/long points on it. I can't find a simple working example using sharmap v2 that actually can compile.

I don't want to put these shape files in to a map engine at run time, just save the files off to the disk.

The closest thing I could find is here, but targets an older version of the API:
http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/discussions/38358

Comment: As I found in ESRI's Shapefile Technical Description,and it says "This document also provides all the technical information necessary for writing a computer program to create shapefiles without the use of ESRI software".FYI.

Comment: @zionpi, where is this technical description you speak of?

Comment: [ESRI Shapefile Technical Description](http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf),it's an ESRI White Paper from 1998.

Comment: check this link https://sharpmap.codeplex.com/discussions/347029

Comment: I intend to do the same thing as your project, and researched a lot in internet but have not found anything good. have some material to indicate

Answer (score 0):

The SharpMap project is apparently spitted into two main branches on GitHub:

- One is called SharpMap and is pretty active: https://github.com/SharpMap/SharpMap
- The other one is SharpMapV2 and was apparently dead by around 2012 https://github.com/SharpMap/SharpMapV2/

They are both under the same GitHub account so the "branding" of these libraries and their API is pretty confusing.

The SharpMapV2 has some saving capabilities. The Link you provided uses the API of SharpMapV2.

The two project have common developers, maybe the easiest way to know about the status of that feature in both version is to try to get in touch with them and post their answer here.